# Android SQLite leak problems

Tags: android, sqlite, memory-leaks

Hey, I've got my database connection setup in an Android Application but LogCat keep's telling me about a SQLite leak.

```
12-03 15:07:23.169: ERROR/Database(2509): Leak found
12-03 15:07:23.169: ERROR/Database(2509): java.lang.IllegalStateException: /data/data/com.domain/databases/db.db SQLiteDatabase created and never closed
12-03 15:07:23.169: ERROR/Database(2509):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1784)
12-03 15:07:23.169: ERROR/Database(2509):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
12-03 15:07:23.169: ERROR/Database(2509):     at com.domain.DatabaseConnection.openDataBase(DatabaseConnection.java:118)
12-03 15:07:23.169: ERROR/Database(2509):     at com.domain.global.ZonesLoaded.InitZones(ZonesLoaded.java:32)
12-03 15:07:23.169: ERROR/Database(2509):     at com.domain.ZoneActivity.onCreate(ZoneActivity.java:34)
12-03 15:07:23.169: ERROR/Database(2509):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-03 15:07:23.169: ERROR/Database(2509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
12-03 15:07:23.169: ERROR/Database(2509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2411)
12-03 15:07:23.169: ERROR/Database(2509):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
12-03 15:07:23.169: ERROR/Database(2509):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
12-03 15:07:23.169: ERROR/Database(2509):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:648)
12-03 15:07:23.169: ERROR/Database(2509):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:320)
etc...
```

After reading other posts [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123749/android-sqlite-database-leak-found) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280345/sqlite-database-leak-found-exception-in-android), it would suggest that I wasn't implementing the `close` method in my DBAdapter class. However I did create this:

```
public synchronized void close()
{
    if(myDatabase != null)
        myDatabase.close();

    super.close();
}
```

I'm starting to wonder if it is down to how I'm using the database adapter, although I just tested my app on a much faster device (Samsung Galaxy S) and this worked with no problems whatsoever! Does anyone have any tips here?

Thanks

Comment: *I'm starting to wonder if it is down to how I'm using the database adapter*: it might be, but to be able to comment on that we need to see how you use it... :)

Comment: Yea that's true. I'm not looking for someone to write my project as that's not what SO is about, just wondering if anyone else has come across this...

Comment: my apologies if you interpreted it that way, that was not my intention :) I was simply interested in seeing more of your code, because I couldn't tell anything obvious you were doing from from what you've already posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too until I made sure to call *close* explicitly in my activity's onPause method. I tend to follow the pattern of opening the DB on resume/create and close it before a pause (as with all other resources that hold state).

To be very clear, I do not recommend opening/closing a DB on-demand or on an ad-hoc basis. It is almost always best to open the DB up early and keep it open for the duration of your activity and close it when the activity gets suspended.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep the db access on activity when required and close both cursor(if using) and database after its usage to efficiently manage memory resource. This  is an efficient way of keeping it from lekage or lock problems